# Inspect URL and download Image

Tags: java, image, web, web-crawler

My goal is to write a java application which inspects the following URL: https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-1971-28699-12927-58 being able to save the image (a copy of a page belonging to an old book) and navigate to next page, repeating the process. One could manually download the images but I want to automate this task. The problem is I don't know much about web, so I am having a hard time.

I have used my browser's web inspector to see the resources in the URL and was able to conclude that the image can be found here: https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-1971-28699-12927-58.jpg.

So I tried the following snippet:

```
public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String imageUrl = "https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-1971-28699-12927-58.jpg";
        String destinationFile = "./image.jpg";

        saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
}
```

Which didn't really work. I got the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-1971-28699-12927-58.jpg
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
at mainpackage.Main.saveImage(Main.java:25)
at mainpackage.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

So I have two problems: the first one being how to proceed in order to download the image and the second being how to find the URL for the next image, as the URLs don't seem to follow a pattern (like a count).

Comment: looks like the server is blocking hotlink. which means they donno want to you do this if thats the case

Comment: But how can my browser access the image? I can do that, right click and "save as".

Comment: well idk..not too sure about how this works, only heard of it. But 500 code means internal server error, and this should not happen on image downloading which is direct access.

Comment: The server may be checking your user-agent (or other HTTP metadata), and blocking requests based on the user-agent. Right now, you aren't setting any user-agent. (But your browser does set a user-agent when making the request.)

Comment: How can I set that from my code?

Comment: Use `URLConnection` instead of `InputStream`. (`URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();`, then `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "some user-agent copied from a typical browser's user-agent");`)

Comment: Using URLConnection and then InputStream is = connection.getInputStream(); didn't work. Same error.

Comment: I have posted a full, working answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```java
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class StackOverflowTest {

    public static void saveImage(final String imageUrl, final String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        final URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        final HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        final InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        final OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception {

        final String imageUrl = "https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.3.1/TH-1971-28699-12927-58.jpg";
        final String destinationFile = "./image.jpg";

        saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the web server expects the `Accept` header, and was failing since it couldn't find it, returning a 500 response. (Also, the image URL performs a redirect.)

As for finding the next image: This is a more complicated task. If there is not an easy way to identify the next image, you probably need to look into XML/HTML parsers for Java. A good, fast one is Jsoup (http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I will try to find a solution for the second problem!